# SQL Server Connection Timeouts

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

Our SQL Server 2008 has been working for quite a while, but then we suddenly got connection timeouts.

We couldn't find an answer to the problem and ended up enabling Named Pipes just to get our applications working, but this is not a great solution (some apps we have to open twice, first time fails second time it fires up)

Anyone know what we can check to fix our TCP connections/configuration?

Comment: Were you connecting from your desktop or another database server? etc?

Comment: In the surface area configuration for services, what is it set to?

Comment: jl - we're connecting from desktops

Comment: DanBig - Is surface area configuration still available in 2008? I know it 2005, but can't seem to find it for 2008?

Comment: Found the new surface area configuration. It's set to use TCP/IP and Named Pipes. The port for the specific IP range was set to dynamic, but I've now hard coded it to 1433 and it's still not working.

Comment: Are the desktops not connecting at all, or is the connection just unreliable?

Comment: Are you using SQL Express edition? If yes, then turn off AUTO_CLOSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that I found an answer:

The server was using dynamic ports which we changed to use port 1433 only. 
We confirmed that inbound connections were enabled in the firewall settings. 
Disabled SQL Browser
Tested the connection using Telnet and SQL Server Management Studio
Then we switched the SQL Browser back on and tried the named instance login again and it worked.

Not sure why this was a problem, I assumed that dynamic ports should have worked with the SQL Browser Service